# How to create a AI Platform Custom Code Service Agent "service-xxxx@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-ai-platform

We can use the following command to create a service account on AI Platform Unified (GCP):

```
gcloud beta services identity create --service=aiplatform.googleapis.com
```

but this will create only one service account but we need two:

```
"AI Platform Service Agent": servicexxx@gcp-sa-aiplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

we also need to have this second service account created:

```
"AI Platform Custom Code Service Agent":service-xxx@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

the second one has "-cc" in the name and is for custom training.

How can we create automatically the second service account "service-xxx@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com" ?

[service agent](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents)

[access control](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/general/access-control#service-agents)

Comment: You don't have to create them, they are auto-provisionned. What's your issue? You don't see them in the UI? If so, on which page?

Comment: No, I need to create them so I can give the proper role in a terraform script. Everything need to be automated. If we try to run some job, yes teh SA are created but then it will failed because of the missing role. Our DevOps team want to create the SA and assign the proper role in one go and with Terraform (same is done like that for all other GCP services).

Comment: Did you created successfully the service with terraform? If so, the service account exists, you don't need to create it, use it and grant it enough permissions.

Comment: The following "gcloud beta services identity create --service=aiplatform.googleapis.com" is used but just create one of the two SA. The question is how to create the second SA automatically with some command tool like gcloud.

Comment: Understood!! I searched, tried, and I think you can't. Report this case to the support and request a feature request

Comment: 1) I do not understand why you need two "Service Agent" service accounts. That type of service account is used by the service itself and not for/by your applications/tools. The service will only use one Service Agent account. 2) If your goal is to add a role to a service account that was created in another step (enabling a service) then reference the service account and add the required roles.

Comment: Why cant you just use both SA created automatically and grant the necessary permissions to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While waiting for GCP to provide a clean solution, running this dummy job (nothing need to provided by the user in the new project), will automatically create the SA we need :

```
gcloud beta ai custom-jobs create --display-name test1 --region europe-west4 --worker-pool-spec=replica-count=1,machine-type=n1-highmem-2,container-image-uri=gcr.io/google-appengine/python
```

and almost immediatly after the job is submitted, the following will be creating:

```
"AI Platform Custom Code Service Agent":service-xxx@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```